# Bootstrap's textarea renders oddly and ugly in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I'm trying to make theme using Bootstrap and i'm having problems with textarea. it works fine in chrome and chrome based browsers but it looks odd and ugly in firefox. [Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLaXs/22/) (open in Firefox).

How do i fix it??? I want it to look normal. and i don't want to break anything else by fixing this.

```
<div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <textarea id="s" type="text" name="s" value="Enter Text" ></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Why fix it? It's a style decided by FireFox.

Comment: I don't like it. and It's a bug i guess.

Comment: Style it yourself? Have a look at the styles that get applied in chrome and copy those to your CSS file, so it looks the same across browsers ...

Comment: Styles are the same. but firefox somehow ignores the whole thing. anyway the @Danko's solution did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your css part:

```
textarea {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

Comment: Works great in all browsers (incl. IE)